# R: retrieving data via url with OSX El Capitan

Tags: r, macos, osx-elcapitan, weatherdata

My first question, so here goes. I've just updated to OSX El Capitan 10.11.4 and it seems to have broken the excellent weatherData package for me. weatherData essentially builds an http url to get data from Wunderground and this is where the problem is. In summary,

```
a <- read.csv("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LHR/2011/4/15/DailyHistory.html?format=1")
```

gives an error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Replacing http with https and the url works i.e.

```
a <- read.csv("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LHR/2011/4/15/DailyHistory.html?format=1")
```

I'm using Revolution R 3.2.3, OSX 10.11.4.

http still works in Windows, hence weatherData is unaffected.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Thank you!!

Comment: the https seems to be forced by the server anyway and maybe connections cannot manage that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the weatherData package. The `download.file` function has long been limited to http-URLs which was the reason for the release of pkgs: downloader and httr. You could get success by forcing `method=l"libcurl"` like this: `a <- read.csv(url("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LHR/2011/4/15/DailyHistory.html?format=1", method="libcurl"))
`